# How to display plain text from markdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown

I'm assuming that SO stores questions in raw `markdown` format. So how is the plain text preview/summary provided on the questions page? Is there any library to achieve this in Rails? Or are they using some other technique?

Comment: There are some examples here: https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown https://github.com/github/markup https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet